# Multi select datepicker keep selected dates after peage reload

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I using this plugin for multi select days.
http://dubrox.github.io/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/

I need to keep selected days after page reload. I suppose that can be done with jquery cookie? I found how to do this on single select date picker:
http://jsfiddle.net/arunatebel/h1qxv6nz/3/

But this not work on multi select.

The code that I using is:

```
$('#multi-date-pick').multiDatesPicker({
   dateFormat: 'DD, d, m, y',

 /* Run search */  
   onClose: function () {
       $('.searchandfilter select.sf-input-select').trigger('change'); 
    },

});/* End datepicker*/
```

I try this, but this save only the last date.

Here is the code:

```
$('#multi-date-pick').multiDatesPicker({
   dateFormat: 'DD, d, m, y',

   addDates: $.cookie('multi-date-pick'), //get the date after reload and init datepicker

   onSelect: function(date) {  

$.cookie('multi-date-pick', date); //store the date in cookies before submiting form 
}
```

I also try this to save dates:`

```
var date = $('#multi-date-pick').multiDatesPicker('getDates');    

    $.cookie('multi-date-pick', date);
```

But then I got this error when adding dates with:

```
addDates: $.cookie('multi-date-pick'), //get the date after reload and init datepicker
```

Uncaught Extra/unparsed characters found in date: ,Friday, 9, 6, 17,Saturday, 10, 6, 17

Comment: The multidatepicker returns an array of dates. Save the array in the cookie or `localStorage`, then use `addDates` when you reload.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Do you have any sample code for local storage?

Comment: There's an example in the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Convert the array to JSON and store that in `localStorage`.

Comment: Ok, I will try. Any idea how to do it with cookie plugin?

Comment: I think the jQuery cookie plugin does the JSON conversion automatically for you, so just store the array.

Comment: Can you see my code bellow. What I doing wrong? I can only save the last date.